# JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM

Tags: java, awt

I try to run a java project in IntelliJ and get that error:
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
AWT not found

I use Mac OS 10.11 and jdk 1.8

Any solutions for that problem?
I found some information there is a problem with java3d

Answer (score 0):

I found found a solution at [java3d](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#avoidtheloadingofobsoleteversionsinstalledasextensions)

Steps:
First disable System Integrity Protection in OS X:
-> Reboot and press Command + R, go to Terminal and enter: csrutil disable

Then i deleted all old j3d files in /System/Library/Java/Extensions and added the new files to the project (as shown in the blog)

Now it looks like it works.